# Angular Request how it works for nestjsx/crud

Tags: angularjs, parameters, request, http-get, query-string

I've been trying for hours to make it work and I can't do it, I hope some of you have the answer to my question because it must be very simple and I am a beginner
I am using AngularJs and NestJs in Nest used the `@nestjsx/crud` and I went trow the [request docs](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Requests) so, here is the problem:

This is my Angular service function

```
getProductsOfPiece(pieceId: number): Observable<ProductSimple[]> {
    return this.http.get<ProductSimple[]>(
      'api/producto/', {
        params: {
          fields: "id,refFabr,refCliente,descrCorta,imagen",
          filter: 'pieza.id||$eq||'+ pieceId
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

This request gives me a `400` Bad Request, it looks like this:

```
/api/producto/?fields=id,refFabr,refCliente,descrCorta,imagen&filter=pieza.id%257C%257C$eq%257C%257C1
```

I imagine the `%` and the hexadecimal have something to do with the URI coding and tried to encode/decode it, but didn't work.

I also tried using the class `RequestQueryBuilder` of `@nestjsx/crud-request` from the [FrontEnd usage](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Requests#frontend-usage) referenced in the docs, and append it to the URL

```
 let queryString = RequestQueryBuilder.create()
      .select(["id","refFabr","refCliente","descrCorta","imagen"])
      .setFilter({
        field: "coleccion.id",
        operator: CondOperator.EQUALS,
        value: collectionId
      }).query();
 return this.http.get<ProductSimple[]>(
      'api/producto/?'+queryString
 );
```

but got worse result

```
/api/producto/?fields=id%2CrefFabr%2CrefCliente%2CdescrCorta%2Cimagen&filter%5B0%5D=pieza.id%7C%7C%24eq%7C%7C1
```

What I don't understand is how I do this with my Postmand and it works!

```
api/producto/?fields=id,refFabr,refCliente,descrCorta,imagen&filter=coleccion.id||$eq||6
```

How can I make it work, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer, just had to set the `.query(false)` on the `RequestQueryBuilder`, this `boolean` parameter is for `encode`, seams like Angular's `HttpClient` class does some encoding or something to the URL so, anyway

It Works! Here is the code:

```
  getProductsOfPiece(pieceId: number): Observable<ProductSimple[]> {
     let queryString = RequestQueryBuilder.create()
      .select(["id","refFabr","refCliente","descrCorta","imagen"])
      .setFilter({
        field: "coleccion.id",
        operator: CondOperator.EQUALS,
        value: collectionId
      }).query(false);
     return this.http.get<ProductSimple[]>(
      'api/producto/?'+queryString
     );
  }
```

And you need to import
`RequestQueryBuilder` of `@nestjsx/crud-request`

> npm i @nestjsx/crud-request.

Any observations are welcome...

UPDATE
To create or update

Here are de docs
Create One https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#create-one-resource
Update One https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#update-one-resource

Following that guide the create and update are simple
Just do POST to the API 'api/producto/' (for example) with the object as body in the request
For the Update follows similar just using the PUT method and the API with the model id 'api/producto/1' (for example)

Comment: I understand perfectly how to make a select request with your explanations, but how to make a request trying to create or update an element and not just read it?

Comment: I have added some extra info to help you. @Iabelle